# Create a string (text) that declares variable and its value, for use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am messing with Javascript code that needs to have variable dynamic part.

I am trying to substitute this piece of Javascript code:

```
var data = document.getElementById('IDofSomeHiddenField').value;
var print = document.getElementById('IDofOutputField');
print.value = data;
```

with something like:

```
var encapsulatedData = "var data = document.getElementById('IDofSomeHiddenField').value;";
var encapsulatedPrint = "var print = document.getElementById('IDofOutputField');";
```

so that when I use somewhere in Javascript code:

```
encapsulatedData;
encapsulatedPrint;
```

this will work:

```
print.value = data;
```

But it does not work.

Is there a way how to declare:

```
var encapsulatedData
var encapsulatedPrint
```

in similar manner like I wrote above, so that:

```
print.value = data;
```

works?

Comment: What the heck are you doing? I can't imagine any scenario where what you want is a good idea! Could you step back and give a broader description of your goal?

Comment: Thank you Francis. I am trying to do sth like can be done on server side in C#: 'string encapsulatedData = "var data = (document.getElementById('IDofSomeHiddenField').value;";' and then you can add that to Javascript block (server side) like: 'string addtoblock = @"function somename(){..." + encapsulatedData + @"......};'. I had it implemented on server side and then inject it to .aspx page. But because the Javascript changes with every postback, ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock was working only for the first time. So I am trying to find a workaround. I wrote more to your comment below.

Comment: Create a new question (or update the current question) with your *actual* problem, which is really an ASP problem not a JS problem.

Comment: So you think that it is not possible to recreate the C# example I have given in Javascript?

Comment: To come up with the best solution requires more context than you are giving. Creating JS strings to execute is almost certainly the wrong approach. Probably you need to have a single unchanging set of code on the JS side that you initialize with data either injected on the server side or retrieved from the client via AJAX. Either way you need to improve your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try to improve it. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error I think. You're not closing the parentheses on the first and second lines.

```
var data = document.getElementById('IDofSomeHiddenField').value;
var print = document.getElementById('IDofOutputField');
print.value = data;
```

It is also bad form to use JS evaluation like you're attempting to do. If anything you really want to create a function for each of the page elements that returns the page element. ECMAScript 5 has properties which I think is sort of what you're looking for with what you're trying to do but that isn't how ECMAScript 3 JS can work.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. But it does not work even when I fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean magically create global variables?

```
function encapsulatedData() {
    window.data = document.getElementById('IDofSomeHiddenField').value;
}
function encapsulatedPrint() {
    window.print = document.getElementById('IDofOutputField');
}
encapsulatedData();
encapsulatedPrint();

print.value = data;
```

This is not very sanitary code, and what you want is probably not what you should be doing. Could you step back and say what your *goal* is, rather than the *means* to that goal?  I suspect what you really want to be using are closures or returning first-class functions for delayed evaluation.

For example:

```
function makePrinter(id) {
    var outputfield = document.getElementById(id);
    return function(value) {
        outputfield.value = value;
    }
}
function getValue(id) {
    return document.getElementById('IDofSomeHiddenField').value;
}

var data = getValue('IDofOutputField');
var print = makePrinter('IDofOutputField');

print(data);
```

Comment: I have got a piece of Javascript on .aspx page. On PostBack, in the C# code behind, I create "random" string of the format `code`"var data = document.getElementById('IDofSomeHiddenField').value;"`code` that is put into TextBox. After PostBack the Javascript gets the value from the TextBox and should use it. I am trying to do sth like can be done on server side in C#: (`code`string encapsulatedData = "var data = (document.getElementById('IDofSomeHiddenField').value;";`code` and then
`code`string addtoblock = @"function somename(){..." + encapsulatedData + @"......};`code`), but with Javascript.